# Issue with Neteller API REST API

Tags: php, api

I have an issue trying to implement Neteller's REST API. I have created my app in the merchant account (I don't have an SSL certificate in my site), I have a static IP for my web site and it is added to Neteller's allowed IP list, but for some reason I always receive a null response back from them.

This is my code:

```
$username = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$password = 'XXxxxxxXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.neteller.com/v1/oauth2/token?grant_type=client_credentials");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type:application/json", "Cache-Control:no-cache"));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array("scope"=>"default"));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$serverOutput = curl_exec($curl);
$info = curl_getinfo($curl);

echo $serverOutput; // null response
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: [This question might help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18891030/how-to-develop-neteller-direct-api-with-php)

Comment: Hello Robbie, i was using that, but for some reason, it stop working, and i receive an error saying that "curl cant connect to : https://api.neteller.com/netdirect". thanks for your quick answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are receiving a null response to the curl_exec() method, this could indicate a problem establishing the HTTP connection.

try adding:

```
print_r(curl_errno($curl));
```

This will return the curl error code, which you can then check against [this list](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html).

Most probably it is a problem establishing the SSL connection - because the certificate issuing authority is not trusted by your cUrl installation. You can fix this by updating the trusted certificate authorities list. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31830614/4676855).